# Locking down SSH firewall rules

Tags: google-compute-engine

The default firewall rules allow SSH access from anywhere.  I want to lock them down to the GDC browser based ssh and our own corporate IP sources.  Only issue I have is I don't know what mask to allow for the GDC.  It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#ssherror) seems quite clear:

> ... Source IP addresses for browser-based SSH sessions are dynamically allocated by Cloud Developers Console and can vary from session to session. For the feature to work, you must allow connections either from any IP address or from Google's IP address range which you can [retrieve using public SPF records](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764). ...

That link then explains that the current IP-address ranges used by Google are stored in DNS and can be retrieved as follows:

```
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks2.google.com 8.8.8.8
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks3.google.com 8.8.8.8
```